# How to check if a given character is considered as 'special' by the Python regex engine?

Tags: python, regex, special-characters

Is there an easy way to verify that the given character has a special regex function?

Of course I can collect regex characters in a list like `['.', "[", "]", etc.]` to check that, but I guess there is a more elegant way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use `re.escape`. For example:

```
>>> re.escape("a") == "a"
True
>>> re.escape("[") == "["
False
```

The idea is that if a character is a special one, then `re.escape` returns the character with a backslash in front of it. Otherwise, it returns the character itself.

Comment: Yeah, it works. My thought was that it escapes non-regex characters like "_" and this could cause problems. But it seems for re. functions "\\_" and "_" does the same.

Comment: re.escape doesn't detect if a character is special it only detects if it is non-alphanumeric.  https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) within `all` function as following :

```
>>> def checker(st):
...   return all(re.escape(i)==i for i in st)
... 
>>> checker('aab]')
False
>>> checker('aab')
True
>>> checker('aa.b3')
False
```

Answer (score -1):

Per [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape), `re.escape` will (emphasis mine):

> Return *string* with **all non-alphanumerics** backslashed; this is useful
>   if you want to match an arbitrary literal string that may have regular
>   expression metacharacters in it.

So it tells you whether a character *could be* a meaningful one, not whether it *is*. For example:

```
>>> re.escape('&') == '&'
False
```

This is useful for processing arbitrary strings, as it ensures that all control characters are escaped, but not for telling you which actually needed to be. The simplest approach, in my view, is the one dismissed in the question:

```
char in set(r'.^$*+?{}[]\| ')
```

Comment: The first part should have been a comment on the answers relying on re.escape(). The last part should have been a comment on the question.

Answer (score -1):

Elegance lies in the eyes of the beholder, however (IMHO) this (below) is the most generic/"timeproof" way of checking if a character is considered to be special by the Python Regex engine -

```
def isFalsePositive(char):
    m = re.match(char, 'a')
    if m is not None and m.end() == 1:
        return True
    else:
        return False

def isSpecial(char):
    try:
        m = re.match(char, char)
    except:
        return True

    if m is not None and m.end() == 1:
        if isFalsePositive(char):
            return True
        else:
            return False
    else:
        return True
```

P.S. -
isFalsePositive() may be overkill to check the special case of '.' (dot). :-)

Comment: Why would you use `if` and `else` like that, as opposed to e.g. `return isFalsePositive(char)`?! Even if the approach is sound, the implementation is definitively inelegant (and not compliant with the style guide).